# Envelope Budgeting on Linux

Tags: linux, finance

Back in my Windows days, I used and liked You Need a Budget ([YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/)), which uses [envelope based budgeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_budget#Envelopes). Unfortunately, because it's based on Adobe Air, it doesn't run in Linux, which is now my only OS. I've cobbled something together in GnuCash, but it's inelegant and fussy and my significant other (who doesn't share my accounting background) finds it intimidating. So I'm looking for an alternative that meets these criteria:

- desktop program that runs on Linux natively
- directly supports envelope budgeting

I'm quite willing to pay for the software and would, in fact, prefer a supported commercial product to a FOSS hobby project.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use CrossOver or Wine to run the current version of YNAB in Linux. I do this my self and it works perfectly. Because YNAB is a "system" and not just software, your not going to find a good clone. Specially not one that works with the mobile apps.

Comment: Just for the record I advocate YNAB with CrossOver https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/you-need-a-budget

Comment: Please note that mobile app availability is irrelevant. Also, envelope budgeting is a very old concept that YNAB simply has a very good implementation of.

Comment: I agree it's "nothing new" but they do a darn go job of teaching it, and their software is designed specifically to work with it. I don't think your going to find an alternative that is as good natively. On the YNAB website, barried very deep are downloads of their old spreadsheets that they used to use with the older versions of their "system".